# Symfony 3.4 dont set arguments when i configure it in yaml service config

Tags: symfony, service, yaml, symfony-3.4

i use Symfony 3.4 and i try to migrate an Silex Application to it. So i cant use the autowiring of Symfony.

My service.yml looks like

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
 _defaults:
 # automatically injects dependencies in your services
  autowire: false
  # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
  autoconfigure: false
  # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
  # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
  public: false

  audit.persister.base:
   class: MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister
   calls:
    - method: 'addPersister'
      argument:
       - '@audit.persister_elasticsearch'
```

The compiled cach class looks like:

```
$this->services['audit.persister.base'] = $instance = new \MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister();

$instance->addPersister();
```

An i got the error:

```
 Type error: Too few arguments to function MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister::addPersister(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/api/var/cache/local/ContainerAdjsiif/getAudit_Persister_BaseService.php on line 14 and exactly 1 expected
```

The error is correct. Because the cached class creator does not provide the argument that i have set in config.

Anyone an idea why the argument will not set in generated cache?

Comment: Hint: Cache is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html), you may have:

```
  audit.persister.base:
     class: MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister
     calls:
         - method: 'addPersister'
          arguments:
               - '@audit.persister_elasticsearch'
```

`arguments` with a `s` at the end.

Comment: Thx this helps but now i have in a service that need this service the same:     $a = new \MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister();
$a->addPersister();     Why isn't it taken into account there?

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to se this service in aother, you have to add de dependency in the other service's constructor

Comment: yes this is done in service.yml like     `orm.event_manager.base:  
    factory: 'MyBundle\ORM\Factory\ORMEventManagerProto:createBase'  
    class: Doctrine\Common\EventManager  
    arguments:  
      - '@orm.audit.handler'
      - '@orm.audit.changeset_normalizer'
      - '@validation_manager'
      - '@annotations.reader'
      - '@acl_manager'
      - '@property_accessor'
      - '@services.propertyExpansion'
      - '@Doctrine\Common\Cache\ChainCache'
      - '@audit.persister.base' `

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to formt it

Comment: I inject now in the factory the service container and getting it directly from there....  This works but it seams that it not work with factory combination.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony it's convention to write calls in one line:

```
services:
    audit.persister.base:
        class: MyBundle\Security\Audit\Persister\ChainedEntityTrailPersister
        calls:
            - ['addPersister', ['@audit.persister_elasticsearch']]
```

Also, you can use PHPStorm with [Symfony plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) for autocomplete. Thanks to that, you're saved from typos and it basically writes for you :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. Where do you have this information about the convention. When you take a look in https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/calls.html there are documented as i am use.

Comment: Hi, documentation != convention. I'd look for code on Github in Symfony + bundles: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/search?l=YAML&q=%27calls%27&type= I use Symfony for 5 years, make bundles, applications above it, but I never saw using "arguments" explicitly in Yaml configs.

Comment: Tanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome! If you migrate bigger chunks of code (5+ hours of work) from Silex to Symfony, you can use Rector to that (https://github.com/rectorphp/rector)